# How to test single registration page using selenium web driver and provide test report to development team?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, pageobjects

I know basic selenium web driver and also written code using Page Object Model in TestNG frame work for one small application registration and login page.
Bu i don't know, how can provide test report to development team and what are the check points for automation testing please help me.

Example:

Assume my application have two pages like Registration and signin page

My code:

```java
public class Sample {

    Authentication_Locators authenticate;
    WebDriver d = null;


    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
        d = InitDriver.wbDriver("chrome", testData.getProperty("testUrl"));
        authenticate = PageFactory.initElements(d, 
        Authentication_Locators.class);
    }

    @Test (priority = 0)
    public void signIn() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        authenticate.userName.sendKeys("user1");
        authenticate.password.sendKeys("password1");
        authenticate.signin.Click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TesgNG creates HTML report of the execution which is located in the current working directory under results folder with name emailable_report. Also for more accurate reports you can also use Soft and hard asserts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my problem is "What we can report" Not "How we can report " in automation testing,want to know what is the checklist for automation testing like if user signin with valid user name and password means how we can test everytime in automation an report to development team

Comment: please guide me

Comment: Let me take you expample of successful login:

1. Write code to open application, Enter user name and password and then click on Log in button. 

2. You can take any one element which comes after successful login on the screen and check for it's existence like below:

if(driver.findelement(<xpath>).exist){

Softassert.assertequal("message","message")

}else{

Softassert.assertequal("different message","message")

}

This will post comments in you html report

Comment: Most welcome . If above answer was helpful please mark it as the appropriate answer.